# livedata observe event triggered at each fragment onStart

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

I am having issues with LiveData.

I have 3 fragments A (menuFragment), B (doThingsFragment), C (displayMessageFragment).
We can move from A to B, from B to C and finally from C to A.

On the onStart method of doThingsFragment, I observe LiveData From doThingsViewModel and I move to displayMessageFragment when this value changes.

**doThingsViewModel :**

```
private var _message : MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()
var message : LiveData<String> = _message 

fun someFunction() {
    _message.value = "blablabla"
}
```

**doThingsFragment :**

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()

    mViewModel!!.message.observe(
        viewLifecycleOwner,
        Observer<String>
        {
            msg ->
            if(!msg.isNullOrEmpty() && mViewModel!!.toastType.value != null){
                val args = Bundle()
                args.putString("message", msg)

                Navigation.findNavController(requireView()).navigate(R.id.mountUnmountValidationFragment, args)
            }
        })
}
```

It works great the first time I update _message (we go from B to C as expected).
However, when I try to move from A to B again, we go into doThingsFragment observer callback again and I move on to fragment C before fragment B is even displayed.

Since _message value has not changed, I **expect not to trigger the observer callback everytime doThingFragment.onStart method is called...**

What am I missing ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

It is the way how livedata behave, if you need receiver event only one time, google or stackoverflow about `SingleLiveData`

Answer (score 0):

`LiveData` works on an Observer pattern, where something registers as an observer, and every time the thing it's observing changes, it gets notified. It's worth [reading the docs on this](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/LiveData#observe(androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner,%20androidx.lifecycle.Observer%3C?%20super%20T%3E)):

> Adds the given observer to the observers list within the lifespan of the given owner. The events are dispatched on the main thread. **If LiveData already has data set, it will be delivered to the observer**.

> When data changes while the owner [`LifecycleOwner`, e.g. the `Activity`] is not active, it will not receive any updates. If it becomes active again, **it will receive the last available data automatically**.

These are the important points - when you register to `observe` the data, you'll immediately be notified of the most recent value (if there is one), *not just when there's a change*. So you can't rely on that callback triggering as a signal that you need to move from `B` to `C`.

What you actually need to do depends on your app logic, how you can tell the difference between "fragment B just displayed, here's a value, and now I need to show fragment C" and "fragment B just displayed, here's a value, but I happen to know I don't need to show fragment C this time". You could do things with setting an `initialised` flag the first time you receive some data (might need to persist that state in `onSaveInstanceState`) or holding the last-seen value (harder to persist) but you get the idea